# Generate URL for an uploaded file from ExperienceForms Database while working with Sitecore Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

**Environment: Sitecore 9.3**

I have a `Sitecore Form` which consists of the following fields:

- First Name (Single-line Text)
- Last Name (Single-line Text)
- Attachments (Native File Upload Component)
- Submit Button

Attachments are stored in `ExperienceForms Database`, **table**: `sitecore_forms_filestorage.FileStorage`. How to create a functionality where URL should be generated for each uploaded file to download it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of all form entries from the ExperienceForms Database.

```
            var result = new List<FormEntry>();
            var output = dataProvider.GetEntries(formId, startDate, endDate);
            if (output != null && output.Any())
                result = output.ToList();
```

for GetEntries, you can use IFormDataProvider interface.

```
namespace Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data
{
  public interface IFormDataProvider
  {
    IReadOnlyCollection<FormEntry> GetEntries(
      Guid formId,
      DateTime? startDate,
      DateTime? endDate);

    void CreateEntry(FormEntry entry);

    void DeleteEntries(Guid formId);
  }
}
```

I've not worked on storage but based on my understanding so far, I think you can create a custom FileStorageProvider class and generate the link field property based on your need -

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/manage-file-storage-for-forms.html

So the idea is if you have [FormItemID] reference in storage, you can first get the forms, (As mentioned above) and based on [FormItemID] reference you can get the files from the custom repository with the custom property of link.

I hope these details will help.